# Cholesky Decomposition of the Hilbert Matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

I would like to have an analytical expression for the Cholesky decomposition of the following matrix:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf A = \left [
\begin{array}{cccc}
1/1  &  1/2  &  1/3  &  1/4 \\
1/2  &  1/3  &  1/4  &  1/5 \\
1/3  &  1/4  &  1/5  &  1/6 \\
1/4  &  1/5  &  1/6  &  1/7 \\
\end{array}
\right ].
\end{equation}

Really, I would be interested in any proof that it is positive definite.

Comment: Do you mean, something like using *[WA*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cholesky+%7B%7B1,1%2F2,1%2F3,1%2F4%7D,%7B1%2F2,1%2F3,1%2F4,1%2F5%7D,%7B1%2F3,1%2F4,1%2F5,1%2F6%7D,%7B1%2F4,1%2F5,1%2F6,1%2F7%7D%7D)?

Comment: Thank you for your help, Moo.  WA's output is helpful, but what I would really like is to be able to express the (i,j)th element of A in terms of i and j.

Comment: I would think searching for Cholesky Decomposition of Hilbert Matrix would locate something.

Comment: Ah, it's called the "Hilbert Matrix"!  Thanks, Moo!  That's the lead I needed!

Comment: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF03167904#page-1

Comment: Thanks again, Moo.  You're my favorite person, right now.  :)